# C recursive permutations

Tags: c, recursion, permutation

i have been trying to complete figure out this part of my assignment to no avail for the past day, and require some help or guidance to help understand the problem.

so far i have this:

```
swap(int A, int B){
    int temp;
    temp = A;
    A = B;
    B = temp;
}


int max_array(int array[], int arraySize)
{
   int i, max=-32000;
   for (i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
   {
     if (array[i]>max)
     {
        max=array[i];
     }
   }
   printf("%d \n Max array: ", max)
   return(max);
}

int nextPermutation(int array[], int arraySize){
    int i;
    n = max_array(array, arraySize);
    if (int i; n == array[i] && i > 1; i++){
        swap(array[i], array[i-1]);
    }

    else if(int i; n == array[i]; i++){


    }
}

void main(){

    int intArray[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    //int intArray[10] = {1, 10, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 4, 5};
    nextPermutation(intArray, 10);
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%d ",intArray[i]);
    }


}
```

But the question that i'm struggling to understand is
"If a1,...,an is an arbitrary permutation (where a1,...,an are the numbers 1, 2, …, n in a probably different order) then the “next” permutation is produced by the 
following procedure: 
(i) If the maximal element of the array (which is n) is not the first element of the 
array, say n=ai , where i>1 , then to produce the "next" permutation you 
need to swap ai and ai−1 . 
(ii) If the maximal element of the array is in the first position, i.e. n=a1 , then to 
produce the “next” permutation to the permutation (a1,...,an)
, first find the “next” permutation to the (n-1)-element permutation (a2,...,an
), and then append a1 to the end of thus obtained array of (n-1) elements."

so it needs to permutate every single possible combination with the array of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and then finish when it reaches this point "(n, …, 2, 1). And this is 
the only permutation that does not have the "next" permutation to it."

And the function int 'nextPermutation(int array[], int arraySize){' needs to stay the same.

Any help or tips will be excellent!

Comment: That swap function won't do anything.

Comment: swap is neither returning a value, nor the parameters are pass by reference. Fix that first

Comment: `main` should return `int`, too.

Comment: Would just adding Void for the swap function still work? All the examples i have found with the swap function do not have a return, so like void swap(int A, int B).

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors in your program,

```
swap() function will not affect the program as it doesn't use pass by reference.

max_array() should find the index of the maximum value, not the maximum value itself.

There is no recursion in your program as far as I can see.

main() should return int.
```

The program fragement given below might give you an idea,

```
    int ct=-1,n=10,temp[10]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int intArray[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    permute(int k) 
    {     
            int i;     
            temp[k]=++ct;     
            if(ct==n-1)     
            {         
               for(i=0;i<n;i++)         
               {
                      printf("%d",intArray[temp[i]]);         
               }
               printf("\n");     
            }     
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)     
            {
               if(temp[i]==0)     
               {
                   permute(i);     
               }
            }
            ct--;     
            temp[k]=0;       
    } 

    int main() 
    {     
      permute(0);     
    }
```

Comment: Thanks deepu i'll inspect your code fragment for help! Also i changed the swap function to this:

    void swap(int array[],int A, int B){
        int temp;
        temp = array[A];
        array[A] = array[B];
        array[B] = temp;
    }

And call it with this

    swap(array, i, i-1);

Comment: Hey Deepu, i'm still having troubles understanding the permutation recursion, i have been changing the code over and over haha but i think i'm just screwing it more and more.

Comment: int nextPermutation(int array[], int arraySize){
    int i;
    int n = max_array(array, arraySize);
    printf("%d", n);
    while (arraysize < 10){
        if (n == array[arraySize] && arraySize > 1){
            swap(array, arraySize, arraySize-1);
            nextPermutation(array, arraySize+1);
            swap(array, arraySize, arraySize-1);
        }

        else if(n == array[i]){
            swap(array, arraySize, i);
            nextPermutation(array, arraySize+1);
            swap(array, arraySize, i);
        }
    }

}

Comment: I just re-attempted by chaning parts of your code, but not sure how to make it work properly. with the code you gave me it seems to go on forever, and it only requires one input for the function, so i need to be able to modify it to take in 2 inputs, one which is a array and another some other int that i'm not exactly sure what it should be since its only specified as 'arraySize' so i'm not sure if its 10 because the array is 10 in length or its for something else. I'll keep attempting to get this to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

for swap sample

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int* A, int* B){
    int wk;
    wk = *A;
    *A = *B;
    *B = wk;
}

int main(void){
    int array[] = { 1,2,3 };

    swap(&array[0], &array[2]);

    printf("array[0]=%d, array[2]=%d\n", array[0], array[2]);

   return 0;
}
```